# multiple pipes not working with semaphores in C

Tags: c, pthreads, pipe, fork, semaphore

I am trying to send a message from parent process to child and then the child will send a reply. I am controlling the whole situation with 2 pipes and 3 semaphores. My semaphores are 
`sem_init(&my_sema, 0, 1); sem_init(&my_sema2, 0, 0); sem_init(&my_sema3, 0, 0);`
The idea is 
The parent function down the sema, writes to pipe and up the sema2 so child can run and parent starts waiting on sema3 which will be incremented after the child finishes writing.
But I am not getting output from any side.
Here is my code

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

//define semaphore
sem_t my_sema;
sem_t my_sema2;
sem_t my_sema3;
sem_t my_sema4;

int value;
#define MAX 10

int     fd[2], fd2[2], nbytes;
pid_t   childpid;
char    string[] = "Hello child Process!\n";
char    string2[] = "Hi, parent Process!\n";
char    readbuffer[1024];

void* parentProcess(void *args){
    //wait on sema
    sem_wait(&my_sema); 

    /* close input side to write */
        close(fd[0]);

    /* Send "string" through the output side of pipe */
        write(fd[1], string, (strlen(string)+1));

    //increment the sema so child can read the message 
    sem_post(&my_sema2);


    sem_wait(&my_sema3);

    /* close output fd2[1] to read input */
        close(fd2[1]);


    //read message sent by the child
        nbytes = read(fd2[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
        printf("Child : %s", readbuffer);


    pthread_exit(0);


}
void* childProcess(void *args){

    //wait for sema to become positive
    sem_wait(&my_sema2);

    /* Child process closes up output side of pipe */
        close(fd[1]);

    /* read the parent message */
        nbytes = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));   
    printf("Parent : %s", readbuffer);
    printf("\n");

    /* Child process closes up input side of pipe */
        close(fd2[0]);

    //send reply to parent process
    /* Send "string" through the output side of pipe */
        write(fd2[1], string2, (strlen(string2)+1)); 

        pthread_exit(0);


}
//main thread starts here
int main(){
    printf("in the main\n");
    //we use fd[0] for reading and fd[1] for writing


    //creating the pipes
        pipe(fd);
    pipe(fd2);

    //initialize the semaphore, returns 0 on success
        sem_init(&my_sema, 0, 1);
        //initialize the sema2 to 0 so initially sema is 1 and only parent can send message 
        sem_init(&my_sema2, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&my_sema3, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&my_sema4, 0, 0);

    pthread_t child_thread; pthread_t parent_thread;

    if((childpid = fork()) == -1)
        {
                perror("fork");
        }

        if(childpid == 0)
        {
        printf("Child started\n");
        pthread_create(&child_thread, NULL, childProcess, NULL);
        }
        else
        {   
        printf("parent started\n");
        pthread_create(&parent_thread, NULL, parentProcess, NULL);
        }   

    printf("waiting for threads\n");

    //wait for the threads to finish
    pthread_join(parent_thread, NULL); pthread_join(child_thread, NULL);
    printf("Threads finished\n");

    sem_destroy(&my_sema); /* destroy semaphore */
        sem_destroy(&my_sema2);
    sem_destroy(&my_sema3);
        sem_destroy(&my_sema4);

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Can you post the whole code? This may be wrong: read(fd2[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer)); maybe you  would have the length of readbuffer and not the sizeof.

Comment: @terencehill i just updated the code please see now. Thank you

Comment: first error is sizeof(readbuffer), you can use strlen(readbuffer) or directly 1024 as it is a constant in your code.

Comment: tried but the results are same. @terencehill

Comment: Normally, you simply have the parent write the message on its pipe to the child; the child waits until it gets the message, does its processing, and writes its response to the parent, which is waiting patiently in a read.  There's no need for any semaphores.  Worry about why semaphores are necessary.  Worry a lot.  It is overkill.  In case of doubt, you should identify the length of a message on the pipe, or provide a way of telling when you've reached the end of a message.  For short messages (say 1 KiB or less), it won't matter as long as you make a single write to send the whole message.

Comment: oh, I got it. Let me try this without semaphores. thank you for explaining this  @terencehill

Comment: and please post this explanation as an answer so I can accept it. @terencehill

Comment: Your semaphores are not in shared memory. Every child you `fork()` gets their own copy, so you cannot use them to communicate. See `mmap(MAP_SHARED)`.

Comment: @EOF thank you so much for pointing this :)

Comment: @EOF i think your answer is much better, Please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Adamnick: Your mixing of `fork()` and `pthread_create()` is pretty wonky. You can't `pthread_join()` a `pthread` that was created in another process.